# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 In-process Hosting - Request Abort CancellationToken does not work

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, httprequest, cancellation-token, asp.net-core-2.2

Despite what is claimed in [Microsoft blog post (ASP.NET Core Module section)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/17/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview3-now-available/), I cannot configure IIS in-process hosting with `AspNetCoreModuleV2` to set `HttpContext.RequestAborted` property `IsCancellationRequested` to true, when long-running XHR request from the web browser is aborted with `abort()` function.

XHR Request is cancelled on the browser side and it's clearly visible in network tab in Chrome, but `CancellationToken` in controller's action (nor `HttpContext.RequestAborted`) never get `IsCancellationRequested` property set to `true`.

WebSite `*.csproj` file contains properties:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>inprocess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

`Web.config` seems to be correct too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments="exec &quot;FullPathToMyWebsite.dll&quot;" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Compatibility version for `services.AddMvc` is set to 2.2:

```
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Host is build with defaults, as adviced in documentation:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @wodzu It works properly with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: do you mean NET Core 3.1 as target framework? because there is no Microsoft.AspNetCore 3.1, the latest version is 2.2.0.

Comment: Of course there is ASP.NET Core 3.1. There is upgrade guide on Microsoft Docs from 2.1 to 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and then you have upgrade guide from 3.0 to 3.1

Comment: you're right, i did not see the 3.x packages in my nuget package manager, because they are not compatible with the native .NET target framework (net461 etc.)